# Viewbox scales things too small at high resolutions and scale factors and they are virtually impossible to see

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5, viewbox

I have a grid with one row and some columns. In order to scale correctly the grid content according to the screen resolution and scale selected in the Windows OS, I use a Viewbox.

I also define a style that is applied to all Viewboxes:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Viewbox}">
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
    <Setter Property="StretchDirection" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

And then I enclose every grid column within a Viewbox:

```
<Grid Focusable="True"
      Height="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Animated image -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- Stack panel with icon and text -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- A vertical separator -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- A button -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- Empty dummy column to help distribute space correctly between columns so it will cause next columns to be horizontally right aligned. -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <!-- Help button -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- Three dots button -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=IsAnimatedImgVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
        <v:UserControlAnimatedImg x:Name="UcSpinner" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Label SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Content="{Binding Path=StatusText}"/>
        </StackPanel>
   </Viewbox>

   <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Image
               Margin="10,5"
               Height="24"
               Width="24"
               MaxHeight="24"
               MaxWidth="24"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"                   
               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
               Source="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>

            <Label 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Content="{Binding Path=StatusTxt}"
               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
            </Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="2">
        <Separator Margin="10,5,5,5"
                   Height="26"
                   Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}">
   </Viewbox>

   <Viewbox Grid.Column="3">
       <Button Height="Auto"
               Width="150"
               Command="{Binding ButtonOnClick}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image 
                   Height="24"
                   Width="25"
                   MaxHeight="24"
                   MaxWidth="25"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                   Source="{Binding ImageIcon}"/>

                <TextBlock
                   Margin="10,2,5,2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Text="{x:Static p:Resources.BtnText}"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
                </TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
      </Button>
    </Viewbox>

    <!-- Empty dummy space to help distribute space correctly between columns and
         make next columns to be horizontally right aligned. This column will be blank   
         space.-->
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="4">
        <ContentControl />
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="5">
        <Button Height="25"
                Width="25"
                MaxHeight="25"
                MaxWidth="25"
                Margin="8,0,5,0"
                Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                Command="{Binding BtnHlpClick}">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                   Source="{Binding ImageHelpIcon}"/>
        </Button>
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="6">
        <StackPanel x:Name="PlaceHolder"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="2,0,12,0"
                    Width="27"
                    Height="Auto">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Height="20"
                   Width="20"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                   Source="{Binding ImgThreeDotsIcon}">
                <Image.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Placement="Bottom" Background="#FFFFFF">
                        <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.mnutext}" Command="{Binding MenuOnClick}"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Image.ContextMenu>
            </Image>
        </StackPanel>
  </Viewbox>
```

The problem I am currently facing is that when I switch to high screen resolutions and also I switch to high scale factor (125%, 150%, 175%, 200%, and so on), then the content of the grid is getting smaller and smaller and it is practically impossible to see. The more screen resolution I select, the more smaller is the grid content. The more scale factor I select, the more smaller is the grid content. The problem is that the grid content gets too small and impossible to see.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe instead of cluttering your layout with ViewBoxes everywhere simply scale the application. For example apply a ScaleTransform on the root container of the Window. Wrapping every UI element into a ViewBox should feel wrong I guess.

Comment: Binding a Label (or ContentControl) to a string results in very bad performance. You should use the TextBlock instead.

Comment: Why do you forcefully try to scale your application? It should scale automatically. WPF's rendering engine uses DIP so you don't have to care. Or do you need an OS independent scale factor for your application?

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this. The usual 2 approaches I have seen is to put the entire window content in a viewbox or to apply a user controlled scale factor to the entire window content.

Comment: @Andy yep, only one viewbox as we discussed in a previous post but then i need to put a fixed width for the grid and things are not getting well. When window changes its width, more than 700 which you say to put, then the grid, two last columns, are not being aligned to the rightmost.

Comment: @BionicCode my controls within the grid was not being displayed correctly, there were cut on high screen resolutions and scale factors when user changes it from the OS. Putting only one viewbox as root does not work as i said to Andy. i need las two columns to be placed at the rightmost and they aren't. And if i put a fixed width for the grid, let's say 700, then it works while main window is just the same width, otherwise it look like grid, the two last columns are not positioned to the rightmost.

Comment: Notice that I set no properties on my viewbox and it works fine. It definitely does not create extra gaps.  That's one possible reason. Either that or Wpf particularly likes me.  For whatever reason, the simple plain viewbox works for me.

Comment: You may want to consider cm as your window measurement if you target high res monitors.

Comment: I think you must review your layout. You obviously created a layout that doesn't resize properly. But that's not normal. Once it resizes properly it will scale correctly.

Comment: Stretch uniform is a likely cause of at least some of your problems.

Comment: @Andy i am going to review again and see if using viewbox without properties is working. i'll give you feedback,

Comment: Regardless, I would look at simple first. If you have auto sized cells with viewboxes in them you're going to be in a nightmare world where nothing knows how big it can be.

Comment: If you want to set a "hard limit" for the lowest sizes you could set MinWidth and MinHeight in the controls.